# I am having trouble using sscanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

**I have the following line,**

```
*"1 $This is an open field west of a white house, with a boarded front door.$ 2 -1 -1 -1"*
```

There are six values within this str: Room number, description, north, south,     east, west

----'$' should not be inputted within the description struct variabl

I have used sscanf successfully for the first 2 elements

```
sscanf(line, "%d",&room[count].room_number);
sscanf(line, "%*[^$]%*c%[^$]s", room[count].description);
```

but i am having trouble with retrieving the north, south, east, and west values.

```
"%*[^$]%*[^$] %d"
```

is that the proper delimiter to retrieve the north value (which should be 2) from the str?

Comment: Why don't you use a single sscanf to convert all six? `if (sscanf(line, "%d $ %99[^$] $ %d %d %d %d", &room[count].room_number, room[count].description, &room[count].north, &room[count].south, &room[count].east, &room[count].west) == 6) { /* success */ } else { /* bad line */ }` (assuming `char description[100];`)?

Comment: `sscanf` doesn't track you position in the line. You have to either read everything at once, or start `sscanf` at different positions. Also `%[` and `%s` are two different specifiers, `%[^$]s` will expect 's' in the end.

Comment: @aragaer `"%n"` will track the position in the line.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to code complex `sscanf()` by:

1. Use `#define` and string literal concatenations to form the format.
2. Use `" %n"` at the end to test for success.

This allows clearer coding.  `"%99[^$]"` is the specifier to scan up to 99 *non-dollar sign* characters.  `"%*[^$]%*[^$] %d"` fails primarily because it does not scan in any `$`.

No `s` needed at the end of `"%99[^$]"`. [@aragaer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786304/i-am-having-trouble-using-sscanf-in-c/41788575#comment70762444_41786304)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define F_PRE "*\""
#define F_RML " $"
#define F_RMR "$"
#define F_END "\"*"

int main(void) {
  const char *line = "*\"1 $This is ... door.$ 2 -1 -1 -1\"*\n";
  int Room_number, north, south, east, west;
  char description[100];
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(line, F_PRE "%d" F_RML "%99[^$]" F_RMR "%d" "%d" "%d" "%d" F_END " %n",
      &Room_number, description, &north, &south, &east, &west, &n);
  if (n && (line[n] == '\0')) {
    printf("%d <%s> %d %d %d %d\n", Room_number, description, north, south, east, west);
  } else {
    puts("Fail");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1 <This is ... door.> 2 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to check return value of `sscanf`. It should be 7.

Comment: @aragaer Unclear why suggest 7.  You may want to review `sscanf()` details especially the `"%n"` part - which does not contribute to the return value.  Checking the return value does not improve code's functionality in this case.  If `n > 0`, the entire format was scanned successful including a `"\"*"` after the last `int` thus the return value could only have been 6.  The converse is not true, the return value could be 6 and `n` still 0 as after the last `int`, the scan did not match `"\"*"`.

Comment: I just counted the number of arguments to be set. When I do this kind of parsing I don't use `%n` an rely only on `sscanf` return value. But `%n` may have a point if, for example, last argument is a number and there are some training non-digit characters.